# Publish an length unknown vector message on a topic

Tags: message, msg, topic, publisher, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm trying to publish a self-defined message composed by 4 vector whose length is unknown.
my .cpp code (incomplete) could be the following:

```
std::vector <int> l,d,r,u;
   data_pub_ = it_.advertise<rd_ctrl::proc_data>("data", 1);
//vectors u,d,l,r computation
data.u=u;
data.d=d;
data.l=l;
data.r=r;
data_pub_.publish(data);
```

if it works (i don't know...if there are errors please tell me), how can i define the .msg file?
thank you very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56318/publish-an-length-unknown-vector-message-on-a-topic/) by [mateo_7_7](https://answers.ros.org/users/4299/mateo_7_7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For creating a msg file,create a folder "msg" in ur package directory. In directory create  msg file name.msg with following content:

int32[] l

int32[] d

int32[] r

int32[] u

Also make changes in CMakelist.txt for compiling msg files. If u ur not sure of vector size u can just declare a variable of message type and publish it without assigning them a value.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-27**:
I followed this way to create a message containing an array with unknown size.

But when I assigned some value to the array in the program and publish,
it gave "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when running.

Should I have to declare the size of the array in the program? How can it be done?

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-27**:
I followed this way to create a message containing an array with unknown size.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-27**:
U need to first allot memory. Do it using msg.a.resize(size of vector) or u can push elements into it using " msg.a.push_back(integer value) .